# How to implement disconnect code within a tcp server

Tags: c#, try-catch, chat, tcplistener

So I have created some code which helps me to display a disconnected message when a client disconnects however I am unsure where to place the code. At the moment I have placed it within my catch block howerver it runs everytime the catch block gets called. Below is my code

```
private void doChat()
{
    int requestCount = 0;
    byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
    string dataFromClient = null;
    string rCount = null;

    requestCount = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            requestCount = requestCount + 1;
            NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

            networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);

            dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
            dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));

            Console.WriteLine("From client - " + clNo + " : " + dataFromClient);
            rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount);
            //ConnUsers.Add(clNo);
            Program.broadcast(dataFromClient, clNo, true);                 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(clNo + " Disconnected!");
            ConnUsers.Remove(clNo);
            clientsList.Remove(dataFromClient);
            foreach (var name in ConnUsers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Current Connected Users : " + string.Join(",", name));
            }
            //Console.WriteLine
            break;
        }
    }//end while
}//end doChat
```

I want to be able to call this code below, inside my try block so that any catch exception wont trigger the code.

```
Console.WriteLine(clNo + " Disconnected!");
ConnUsers.Remove(clNo);
clientsList.Remove(dataFromClient);
foreach (var name in ConnUsers)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Current Connected Users : " + string.Join(",", name));
}
//Console.WriteLine
break;
```

I have this problem where the else block is called and straight after the catch block gets fired. This is bad coding however I wanted to know a more suitable way to place the code within my catch block so that it functions properly.

Comment: if i understand you correctly only want to "fire" the catch block at a certain exception. So why don't you just catch the exception, you are expecting?

Comment: @Pulle how can I catch a certain exception where the catch block only runs the code. As I am not sure which exception will suit its purpose. Also the line "dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));" throws an exception which is substring is less than zero. What if condition can I do to stop this. I have tried "dataFromClient.Length <= 0".

Answer (score 0):

Try using System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException, instead of general Exception.

```
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(clNo + " Disconnected!");
        ConnUsers.Remove(clNo);
        clientsList.Remove(dataFromClient);
        foreach (var name in ConnUsers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Current Connected Users : " + string.Join(",", name));
        }
        //Console.WriteLine
        break;
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this However now my programme crashes and displays error :SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. Whever I close a client I use client.Close(); is this closing all clients if im using the same computer?

Comment: Whenever a client connects the server adds it to a list: clientsList.Add(dataFromClient, clientSocket);